# Skipped command in SQLite expression: normal?

Tags: syntax, sqlite

The following SQLite query is accepted by the SQLite shell (version 3.7.5, which is the latest one), despite containing a "strange" insertion of the word `qwerty`:

```
sqlite> select distinct DOB from (select * from MyTable qwerty);
```

It works whatever the word put after `MyTable`.  Is this normal?  I did not find this syntax in the [syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) from the official sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're aliassing the table `MyTable` as `querty`. Since you're not using either name in the rest of the query, this has no effect. The query is expressed by the documentation you linked, it's taking the path in [single-source](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#single-source) that skips `database-name` and `AS`.